# How create database and tables in Entity Framework in C# and WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I build an app that works with MySQL server and I make it do the migration and it works fine.

But I also want to create the database first in Mysql command line, then do the migration.

Like execute this query first, then do the migrations:

```
CREATE database `ahmed` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_general_ci ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
try
{
    string conn = @"server=localhost;userid= ;password= ";
    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(conn))
    {
      connection.Open();      
                    
       string command = "CREATE database `ahmed` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_general_ci;";

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(command, connection);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Created databaase");
     }
}
catch (MySqlException ex)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex);
}
```